# Angular Material Table rowspan columns based on dataSource object array property size

Tags: angular, angular-material

Even now in version 7.2 of Angular Material, I can't seem to find examples on how to use rowspan on mat-table and keep the component functionality.

This is how far (short?) I've got:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wudscb

The example in the Stackblitz above is "almost" what I am looking for, but I am not being able to see how to finish it.

```
...
===============================================
||     ||            ||            ||  row1  ||
||  1  ||  Hydrogen  ||   1.0079   ||========||
||     ||            ||            ||  row2  ||
===============================================
||     ||            ||            ||  row1  ||
||     ||            ||            ||========||
||  2  ||   Helium   ||   4.0026   ||  row2  ||
||     ||            ||            ||========||
||     ||            ||            ||  row3  ||
===============================================
||     ||            ||            ||  row1  ||
||  3  ||  Lithium   ||   6.941    ||========||
||     ||            ||            ||  row2  ||
===============================================
...
```

An example using other metadata format can be found in:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lnahlh

Following my Stackblitz (the first link), my questions are:

Am I too far of achieving this rowspan shim/hack?

How do I loop the rows based on the lenght of the row['descriptions'] size?

What If I had another array property inside the object? Could I iterate and generate the columns/rows/rowspan with its size, so it would become more generic?

I'm trying to find a generic solution for the community.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lnahlh

Comment: @MaihanNijat that example that is found on a Github issue open in material layout works in a very different way. You can find in the sabe Github issue a question about how to do it when the object dataSource has an array inside it how it would be solved.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add expected output?

Comment: @Justcode edited.

Comment: Rather than use a method `getRowSpan()`, I would recommend you add a data field in your object. Data binding to a method is expensive in iteration.

Answer (score 21):

Well, it seems that material table has no api documentation for it, I could not find any trick to do this too, But we can twick the our data to support this, as per your second example we can reform the data to new json and we can get our expected result.

### Step 1 :

```
    const originalData = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2'] },
      { id: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'] },
      { id: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2'] },
      { id: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'] },
      { id: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, descriptions: ['row1'] },
      { id: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'] },
      { id: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, descriptions: ['row1'] },
      { id: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, descriptions: ['row1'] },
      { id: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'] },
      { id: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'] },
    ]; //original data

    const DATA = originalData.reduce((current, next) => {
      next.descriptions.forEach(b => {
        current.push({ id: next.id, name: next.name, weight: next.weight, descriptions: b })
      });
      return current;
    }, []);//iterating over each one and adding as the description 
    console.log(DATA)

    const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = DATA; //adding data to the element data
```

### Step 2

this will be as it is as your second stackblitz link.

```
 getRowSpan(col, index) {    
    return this.spans[index] && this.spans[index][col];
  }
```

### Step 3

as it is as per your second link

```
  constructor() {
    this.cacheSpan('Priority', d => d.id);
    this.cacheSpan('Name', d => d.name);
    this.cacheSpan('Weight', d => d.weight);
  }

  /**
   * Evaluated and store an evaluation of the rowspan for each row.
   * The key determines the column it affects, and the accessor determines the
   * value that should be checked for spanning.
   */
  cacheSpan(key, accessor) {
    for (let i = 0; i < DATA.length;) {
      let currentValue = accessor(DATA[i]);
      let count = 1;

      // Iterate through the remaining rows to see how many match
      // the current value as retrieved through the accessor.
      for (let j = i + 1; j < DATA.length; j++) {
        if (currentValue != accessor(DATA[j])) {
          break;
        }

        count++;
      }

      if (!this.spans[i]) {
        this.spans[i] = {};
      }

      // Store the number of similar values that were found (the span)
      // and skip i to the next unique row.
      this.spans[i][key] = count;
      i += count;
    }
  }
```

### Step 4

Using index to pass down to rowspan and hiding the rows where it doesn't needed

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Priority </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data;let i = dataIndex" [attr.rowspan]="getRowSpan('Priority',i)" [style.display]="getRowSpan('Priority', i) ? '' : 'none'">
         {{ data.id }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data;let i = dataIndex" [attr.rowspan]="getRowSpan('Name',i)" [style.display]="getRowSpan('Name', i) ? '' : 'none'">
         {{ data.name }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data;let i = dataIndex" [attr.rowspan]="getRowSpan('Weight',i)" [style.display]="getRowSpan('Weight', i) ? '' : 'none'">
         {{ data.weight }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="descriptions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Descriptions </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> {{ data.descriptions }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr> 


</table>
```

[Here is the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wudscb-kpjdfv)

Comment: I was trying to implement drag and drop rows with this sample, as per implementation it simply hide spanned rows and show only single row instead, so when I used drag and drop feature it doesn't move the whole spanned row instead it only moves one row out of the spanned row.Can you help with that?

Comment: @Nofi you need to show more details, create an example or separate question.

Comment: I already did.Please have a look  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56007877/mattable-row-span-drag-drop-issue

Comment: Hi @Justcode this answer is very useful for me. But when we have another column with stringArray (two columns with stringArray[]), how can we display that. Please give some example.

Comment: @Hari9513 `mat-row` has that functionality, please explore it you will get to know

Comment: If suppose data is like this
const originalData = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2'], explore: ['explore1', 'explore2' ] },
{ id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2'], explore: ['explore1', 'explore2' ] },
];   How will you display this data in table

Give some example

Comment: @Hari9513 fork my repo and try it, if you still have a question you can ask new question or paste the link here.

Comment: The `[style.display]="getRowSpan('Name', i) ? '' : 'none'"` made the difference

Comment: @Justcode How to add another column with array of values as  like descriptions: ['row1', 'row2']

Comment: @Shimaan what you mean? I don't understand your question

Comment: @Justcode  i would like to display  data  like this const originalData = [ { id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2'], quantity: ['q1', 'q2' ] }, { id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2'], quantity: ['q1', 'q2' ] }, ];   and for alternate rows have to differentiate the colors as like default Mat-table. How to  display like that. kindly advise

Comment: How about e.g. <ng-container *matCellDef="let data;let i = dataIndex"><td mat-cell *ngIf="getRowSpan('Name',i)" [attr.rowspan]="getRowSpan('Name',i)">{{ data.name }}</td></ng-container> instead of <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data;let i = dataIndex" attr.rowspan]="getRowSpan('Name',i)" [style.display]="getRowSpan('Name', i) ? '' : 'none'">{{ data.name }}</td>. It seems a bit silly to add data only to hide it, when you can simply omit it.

Comment: @SvenCazier I agree, it will certainly reduce DOM load

Comment: Awesome solution!! I will just add something. If you need to refresh the table with new data you will need to recalculate the spans by calling this.cacheSpan(). Don't forget to clean this.spans (e.g this.spans = []) before all your new calls. Otherwise you might encounter some issue

Comment: @CyDevos Sure thing

Comment: What if I have multiple values in array format for example: 

let data = [
{"test":[], "description":["row 1","row 2","row 3"], "id":[7,10,60], "name":"record 1"},{"test":[], "description":["row 1","row 2"], "id":[1,4], "name":"record 2"},
{"test":[],"description":["row 1","row 2","row 3","row 4","row 5","row 6","row 7","row 8","row 9"],"id":[1,6,7,10,15,25,26,30,47],"name":"record 3"}]

Answer (score 6):

As I was not happy with the answers presented (especially with the `cacheSpan` implementation).

I came up with something more convenient IMHO, that goes something like:

```
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns = ['priority', 'status', 'dateCreated', 'testNumber', 'testCurrency', 'testTime'];
  dataSource = DATA;

  spans = {};

  constructor() {
    this.spans = Object.assign({}, {
      priority: this.spanDeep(['priority'], DATA),
      status: this.spanDeep(['priority', 'status'], DATA),
      dateCreated: this.spanDeep(['priority', 'status', 'dateCreated'], DATA)
    });
  }

  spanDeep(paths: string[] | null, data: any[]) {
    if (!paths.length) {
      return [...data]
        .fill(0)
        .fill(data.length, 0, 1);
    }

    const copyPaths = [...paths];
    const path = copyPaths.shift();

    const uniq = uniqWith(data, (a, b) => get(a, path) === get(b, path))
      .map(item => get(item, path));

    return uniq
      .map(uniqItem => this.spanDeep(copyPaths, data.filter(item => uniqItem === get(item, path))))
      .flat(paths.length);
  }

  getRowSpan(path, idx) {
    return this.spans[path][idx];
  }
};
```

Working example may be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lnahlh-hw2d3b

Comment: I tried this and the rowSpan is not working as expected when I am pointing to get remote data by using a service. When I am using the same JSON without pulling from service its working as expected.

Comment: @aswininayak there's no difference where does the data comes from, has to be an issue with your implementation...

Comment: Thanks Kyle
There was some ordering issues in this.spans object assign

Answer (score 1):

We must say how many rows there, but some rows has same `id` and we will sort and merge td if them used same id.
But for your data, it is say some rows there, and descriptions is array and split able. For this way JS can't know how many `<tr>` should be there.

2 ways for you:
1- Format your data, keep one description each row, same as the example data in second href, `[{id, name, weight, countdescriptions, description},...]`, and use `[attr.rowspan]='data.countdescriptions'` instead `[attr.rowspan]='getRowSpan(data.id)'`.
2- Update content format, like `<ul><li *ngFor...` in the description `<td>`, and remove the `[attr.rowspan]` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

a way simpler approach would be to use ng-containers

html template would be something like this, ex: app.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" multiTemplateDataRows>

<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Priority </th>
       <ng-container *matCellDef="let data">
          <td mat-cell *ngIf="data.id" [attr.rowspan]="rowSpanData[data.id]">
            {{ data.id }} 
          </td>
       </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <ng-container *matCellDef="let data">
      <td mat-cell *ngIf="data.name" [attr.rowspan]="rowSpanData[data.id]">
       {{ data.name }} 
      </td>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <ng-container *matCellDef="let data">
      <td mat-cell *ngIf="data.name" [attr.rowspan]="rowSpanData[data.id]">
       {{ data.weight }} 
      </td>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="descriptions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Descriptions </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> {{ data.description }} </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

JS / TS  file content will be

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  rowSpanData = ROWSPANDATA;
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'weight', 'descriptions'];
  constructor() {  }
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  weight: number;
  descriptions: string[];
}

const originalData = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2'] },
  { id: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'] },
  { id: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2'] },
  { id: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'] },
  { id: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, descriptions: ['row1'] },
  { id: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'] },
  { id: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, descriptions: ['row1'] },
  { id: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, descriptions: ['row1'] },
  { id: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'] },
  { id: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, descriptions: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'] },
]

let DATA1 = []
const ROWSPANDATA = {}
originalData.forEach(row => {
  ROWSPANDATA[row.id] = row.descriptions.length;
  row.descriptions.forEach((desc, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      DATA.push({id: row.id, name: row.name, weight: row.weight, description: 
      desc});
    } else {
     DATA.push({description: desc})
    }
  })
})

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = DATA;
```

just reformat the data to fit in a basic HTML table.

[working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wudscb-chgtgw?file=app/app.component.html)

note: ID field can be duplicated, here i have used ID for simplicity of an answer you can create your own unique key and add it as part of row data and let it not displayed as a table column, that is still fine with angular material table.