# Angular Material: How to make a multi row column in a material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am writing a Material Table like this:

```
<mat-table multiTemplateDataRows [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <h4>TEST</h4>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Title">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="onEditActivityTemplate(element); $event.stopPropagation();">
      <h4>Title: </h4>
      <p>{{element.title || 'None'}}</p>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Time">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Time </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="onEditActivityTemplate(element); $event.stopPropagation();">
      <h4>Time: </h4>
      <p>{{element.time || 'None'}}</p>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Created By">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Created By </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="onEditActivityTemplate(element); $event.stopPropagation();">
      <h4>Created By: </h4>
      <p>{{element.createdBy || 'None'}}</p>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Output">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Output </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="onEditActivityTemplate(element); $event.stopPropagation();">
      <h4>Output: </h4>
      <p>{{element.output || 'None'}}</p>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Description">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="onEditActivityTemplate(element); $event.stopPropagation();">
      <h4>Description: </h4>
      <p>{{element.description || 'None'}}</p>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Divider">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Divider </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="onEditActivityTemplate(element); $event.stopPropagation();">
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['Title', 'Time'];"></mat-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['Created By', 'Output'];"></mat-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['Description'];"></mat-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['Divider'];"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

I somehow need to be able to show an image associated with these rows laid out like this

[image]

So I have 2 questions. 1 Is this possible? And 2 how do I approach this?
As well if it is possible I would like to insert a mat-divider below each data set, however I have been unsuccessful in this as well.

My data is an array of the following object:

```
export interface MaterialImage {
  id: number;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  timestamp: string;
  createdBy: string;
  output: string;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Material Table rowspan columns based on dataSource object array property size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53857049/angular-material-table-rowspan-columns-based-on-datasource-object-array-property)

Comment: Can you post some description of your data structure? Also if you use flex (which is what you're doing with <mat-table> as opposed to <table mat-table>) you will not be able to use colspan/rowspan per the last sentence of the Angular Material table docs: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: I updated the question with the data structure